# Passing a variable to display a django model method

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a django model with a method that depends on the variable `input` that should be read in a form. This method is displayed as a column of a table using `django_tables2` and the values in the column depend on the `input` that the user has introduced in the form.

```
class Task(model.Model):
    ...
    def time(self, input):
        ...
        return value
```

The table that is displayed in the template shows some fields from the above model:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class TaskTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('time',)
```

How could I pass the variable `input` read in a view function to the model method?

Comment: Is this a trick question? `sometask.phase(time)`

Comment: I assume you are calling this method from template. In that case you can't do it. You cannot pass parameter to methods called from template.

Comment: @Rohan true, but it's easy enough to either via Ajax pass it to a handler on the back-end or via a post assign it to a variable he can later use on the form

Comment: @Rohan the method is defined as a column field in a table

Answer (score 1):

lets make the following assumptions

- Template Named: MyTemplate.html
- Url Definition: url(r'^/some/url/defn/$', 'some_app.controller.handler'),
- Form called InputForm

### MyTemplate.html

```
<form method='POST' action='.'> <!-- posts to self -->
   {% csrf_token %}
   <table>
   {% form.as_table %}
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### forms.py

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    # ... other fields
    time = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

    def clean(self):
        """
        your form validations
        """
        cleaned_data = super(InputForm, self).clean()
        time = cleaned_data.get('time')
        # validate your times format here
        if not time_valid(time):  # you need to do your own validation here
            self._errors['time'] = self.error_class(['time is invalid!'])

        return cleaned_data  # always return the cleaned data! always :)
```

### controller.py

```
from some_app.forms import InputForm
from some_app.models import Task


@csrf_protect
def handler(request):
    template_file = 'MyTemplate.html'
    template_info = {
      'form': InputForm()
    }
    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        template_info['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():
            # retrieve your related model here
            task = Task.objects.filter(field='lookupvalue')
            # this makes huge assumptions, 
            # namely that your form validations ensure that the form data 
            # is in the proper format to go into the database
            task.phase(form.cleaned_data.get('time'))

            # save your model data
            task.save()
        else: 
            # spit out any warnings here? 
            pass
     return render(request, template_File, template_info)
```

now point your browser at `http://your_dev_server:[port]/some/url/defn/` you will be presented with a template that upon completing it, will handle some form validations (and respond with errors) and if successful call your `phase()` method against the task object!

Comment: Does task.save() make any changes to the model data? It looks like the method does not have an associated column in the database.

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro I'm not really certain, i called for the save because I do not know if your phase() method performs any hidden work or additional side effects.  Look at the method definition and you can determine if the save is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Now your Task model object can access phase function so you can use just

some_var = Task.phase(time)

after importing Task in the views,
here Task object acts as self and time is send for time

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following `__init__` method for the table of this object to be able to pass the parameter read in the form as `TaskTable(tasks, dt=input_datetime)`:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class TaskTable(tables.Table):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "dt" in kwargs: self.dt = kwargs.pop("dt")
        super(TaskTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('time',)

    def render_time(self, value, record):
        if hasattr(self, "dt"):
            return record.time(input=self.dt)
        else:
            return value
```